# When programming in Android, do I need a cursor to retrieve a simple read-only value from SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I am from a PHP background where I never used cursors.

I have followed the Google Android Notepad example where I got practice using cursors and database adaptors. I vaguely understand the point of the cursor is "to assist with the life cycle activities that happen in Android" or quoting the example, "...that allows Android to take care of the Cursor lifecycle instead of us needing to worry about it".

My question is if you're doing something simple like obtaining a read-only value, is it still the best idea to use a cursor? Is there maybe some other better (faster) way of retrieving the data? Using a cursor seems more overhead than needed for this particular query.

The point of the code below is to obtain the number of items in a cart.

```
public long getNumItemsInCart(Long rowId) throws SQLException {
        Cursor mCursor =
            mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NUM_ITEMS_IN_CART}, KEY_ROWID + "='" + rowId + "'", null,
                    null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor.getLong(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ProductsDbAdapter.KEY_NUM_ITEMS_IN_CART));        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any other better (faster) way of getting a simple value from the database.

You can of course put your own layer of code between your database (ContentProvider) and your application logic where you can create your own convenience methods for performing such manoeuvres. But, as you surely already know, an extra layer might cause you performance penalties if not written properly.

You could also cache your simple value (read it once, during initialization and save it in an appropriate member field of your class). But this would mean that you loose control over it's life cycle. You can't call a "re-query" directly on a Long or Integer value (there is no such thing as `Long.requery()`).

So, yes, having an entire Cursor object for a single value might seem overkill for some use-cases, but then; it's not the most common use-case to retrieve a single value (one column, one row) from a database. For such values you would perhaps use the `SharedPreferences` infrastructure. Most likely you will get several columns and several rows from a database, and from that perspective I think you will find the Cursor object very handy.